# Writing on same file using Oracle

Tags: file, plsql, oracle10g

How can i use same file (like `ABC.txt`) to write using `UTL_FILE`.

Currently what is happening is whenever i am trying to write on `ABC.txt` previous entry is getting deleted or replaced with latest entry. I want all the entries I have made  be present.
I am using Oracle 10*g* PL/SQL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understood you well, you want to append new lines to an existing file (keeping existing content). In this case you need to open the file in append mode:

```
file_handle = utl_file.fopen( directory, 'file_name', 'a' );
```

That should be it.